# R Run chunk while folded/hidden in Rmarkdown RNotebook

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I'm struggling to find anything like this on forums or manuals, but I would like to find this feature.

Is there a way to run a chunk in Rstudio while keeping it hidden like below?

[image: The chunk is hidden here]

This feature would be great when writing documentation/write-up within the same file and testing and updating the code.

As far as I can see, whichever way I run it, it unfolds/shows the chunk contents like below.

[image: The chunk is no longer hidden]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when setting `chunk output in console` in settings, then running the chunks via `ctrl+alt+R` or `ctrl+shift+enter` or `mouse click on the run button` keeps them folded while running.

Only setting `chunk output inline` unfolds the chunks obligatorily it seems.